# Python: How to count a list of strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small program that will count a list of strings and print said strings in alphabetical order with the number of occurrences.

This is what I have so far:

```
from collections import Counter
def funct(list):
  count = Counter(list)
  print(count)

funct(['a','c','a','a','c','b'])
```

Current output is:

*Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1})*

How I can reformat the output including sorting the strings?

Desired output is:

```
a 3

b 1

c 2
```

Comment: @PaSTE. Definitely by key.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter
def funct(list):
  count = Counter(list)
  for item in sorted(count.items()):
      print(item[0], item[1])

funct(['a','c','a','a','c','b'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a 3
b 1
c 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sorted function before printing it:

```
for keys,values in sorted(count.items()):
```